# Open file in Eclipse through URL handler

Tags: java, eclipse, xdgutils

In my project, I have a special JSP which displays the exception stacktrace in case of Exceptions.

Is there a way to use an URL handler or something else which would have Eclipse open a file? Maybe with `xdg-open`?

I use Eclipse 4.3 on Kubuntu Linux.

Comment: TeamCity's plugin does this somehow. I suppose you could write an eclipse plugin that starts a miniature web server say on port 9998, then when you try to load a url like localhost:9998:///path/to/file.ext:66 it will send a dummy response, and will open the file in eclipse (maybe it could also active the window). Looking at play's dev error page, the link could have target set to a hidden iframe.

Answer (score 2):

I've ended up with this solution:

1. Edit `xdebug.ini` (it should be somewhere like `/etc/php/7.0/mods-available/xdebug.ini`), add:

   ```
   xdebug.file_link_format="xdebug://%f(%l)"
   ```

   Restart your server or php-fpm. For Apache on Ubuntu use `sudo service apache2 restart`.
2. Create `eclipse-launch.sh`. It is intended to parse URL and pass a file to Eclipse. You can name it as you want and put it anywhere you want, I've placed it in the eclise directory. Be sure to replace `/home/user` with your actual home directory and `path="..."` with actual eclipse path:

   ```
   #! /bin/bash

   arg=$1
   path="/home/user/eclipse/eclipse-neon/"

   # file name directly followed by a line number in parenthesis
   regex="//([^(]*)\(([0-9]+)\)"

   if [[ $arg =~ $regex ]]
   then
       file=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
       line=${BASH_REMATCH[2]}
       $path/eclipse --launcher.openFile "$file"+"$line"
   else
       msg="Unsupported URL: $arg"
       zenity --info --text="$msg"

       # alternatives:
       # notify-send "$msg" # another notification program
       # $path/eclipse # just run eclipse
   fi
   ```

   Read more about Eclipse command line options here: [http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.platform.doc.isv/guide/product_open_file.htm](http://help.eclipse.org/mars/index.jsp?topic=%2Forg.eclipse.platform.doc.isv%2Fguide%2Fproduct_open_file.htm)
3. Give the file executable permissions: `chmod +a eclipse-launch.sh`
4. Create `xdebug.desktop` at `~/.local/share/applications/`. It will be used by `xdg-open` (Chrome uses xdg-open by default).

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Comment=
   Exec=/home/user/eclipse/eclipse-neon/eclipse-launch.sh "%u"
   Icon=/home/user/eclipse/eclipse-neon/eclipse/icon.xpm
   Name=Eclipse xdebug Launch
   NoDisplay=false
   StartupNotify=true
   Terminal=0
   TerminalOptions=
   Type=Application
   MimeType=x-scheme-handler/xdebug;
   ```
5. Run `xdg-mime default xdebug.desktop x-scheme-handler/xdebug`. This should add an entry to `~.local/share/applications/mimeapps.list` to `[Default Applications]` section. The entry itself should look like `x-scheme-handler/xdebug=xdebug.desktop`
6. For Firefox follow instructions from here: https://xdebug.org/docs/all_settings#file_link_format

   - Open `about:config`
   - Add a new boolean setting `network.protocol-handler.expose.xdebug` and set it to `false`
   - The first time you click on xdebug:/// link Firefox will prompt you to select an application to run, point to the created **eclipse-launch.sh** file.